Add header to Spring boot Oauth2 client token request used within feign
I've set up a Feign client to interact with an API. This API requires the client to first fetch an Access Token via oAuth2, which then needs to be passed in an Authorization header in the actual request to the API.
One of the additional requirements of the API is that I need to pass in an additional header when requesting the token and when doing the subsequent request. For the subsequent request I can use a RequestInterceptor. However, this isn't used when the oauth call is beind done. So: how can I add an extra header when doing the oauth2 call for token?
I came across this post, however that is based on configuring a WebClient.
The above I've set up by setting up an oauth2 configuration and using Feign's OAuth2AccessTokenInterceptor bean:
application.yml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          arrow:
            clientId: ...
            clientSecret: ...
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
            client-authentication-method: client_secret_basic

FeignConfiguration
@Bean
OAuth2AccessTokenInterceptor oauth2AccessTokenInterceptorOne(final OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
     return new OAuth2AccessTokenInterceptor("arrow", authorizedClientManager);
}


Have you tried using a transformer? https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/docs/current/reference/html/#transform-the-load-balanced-http-request
